# Why does sound need air in order to travel?

Tags: acoustics, pressure

I know that in space, because of vacuum that we can't hear voices or sound to be specific, why is that? Why does sound need a medium to go through?

Comment: It's like you can not make hot chocolate without chocolate.

Comment: Without chocolate or heat!  Pressure waves propagating through a medium such as air is what the word "sound" _means_.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel What about white hot chocolate? It has no cocoa, which is like hot chocolate without chocolate

Comment: @Jim No problem at all! White chocolate does not contain the dark solids, but only the fat component of cocoa, which is slightly more than half of it. So if you accept that low fat milk is milk, it should help to accept white hot chocolate as low solid chocolate. Oops, I digressed...

Comment: @VolkerSiegel No, skim milk is water that's lying about being milk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sound is a [pressure wave](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/u11l1c.cfm):

[image]

Each vibration compresses the molecules and that compression propagates onwards. In order for sound to exist, we need something to be compressed. In space, the particles floating about probably aren't close enough to compress and make anything audible (I haven't traveled to space to test this, and I don't think anyone who has gone to space has tried it either).

Comment: Densities in space are low, but not so low to prevent all sound from propagating. Pressure waves with wavelengths much (much much?) longer than the typical interparticle separation can still propagate. This wouldn't be within the human audible range, but fits the definition of sound as a pressure wave. For instance: http://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/universe/black_hole_sound.html

Comment: @Kyle: I was thinking *audible* and wrote *sound*. I'm amending this now

Answer (score 2):

Sound, by definition, is vibration of medium. So, you can't imagine sound without a medium.

A sound source like Drum vibrates the air molecules making sound wave. When this wave reaches your ear, it vibrates your ear drum which is processed by your brain.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what sound is - waves, or oscillations, of a medium.

Different things produce air (water) oscillations and humans, like many other animals, developed a device - called ear - that can discern these oscillations and our brains learned to make sense of it.

So no medium, as in vacuum, means no waves of a medium, and therefore no sound.

That's all there is to it :)

Answer (score 1):

**That's because sound is a mechanical wave.** [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_wave):

> A mechanical wave is a wave that propagates as an oscillation of
>   matter, and therefore transfers energy through a medium.

Most notably:

> A mechanical wave requires an initial energy input. Once this initial
>   energy is added, the wave travels through the medium until all its
>   energy is transferred. In contrast, electromagnetic waves require no
>   medium, but can still travel through one.

**Since a vacuum is defined as lacking a medium, then sound and correspondingly, mechanical waves, *cannot propagate through a vacuum***. This is why we can't hear voices or sounds in space.

Comment: Space isn't a vacuum. Densities in the interstellar medium are around 1 particle per cubic centimeter. In the solar neighborhood, it's around 10 particles/cm$^3$. Compare these values to the number density of air on earth at $\sim10^{25}$ particles/cc. It's certainly small, but not really a vacuum.

Comment: Also, welcome to Physics.SE ;)

Comment: @KyleKanos: I had expected you to make a comment like that! ;) You're quite right about the interstellar medium, but I was referring to space in general. Nonetheless, as we still can't produce a density that low on earth, space and to some extent even the interstellar medium, serves as a good "spherical cow" (within reason) to represent "the vacuum". And, thank you for the greeting: it's a pleasure to make your acquaintance! ;)